# i have created a search page that shows ads but only my top most ad works remaining don't. images and code are included

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have created a search page that is displaying ads. when the user clicks the enroll button i want to get the course id and email of that ad(these will be sent to a form later).the problem is when user clicks enroll, for the first ad all emails of all ads are displayed on the console and for course id i get undefined. for all the remaining ads i don't get any thing at all.
[i have provided an image for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyX8W.png)

here is the code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/basic.css">
    <script src="js/jQuery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="css/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Forms/form-validation.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require 'connection.php';
include_once 'utlities.php';
$userEmail=$_SESSION['user'];
$form_string = 'd';

$sqlQuery ='SELECT * FROM `course` WHERE `course_title` LIKE "%'.$form_string.'%" OR `user_teacher` in (SELECT user_teacher FROM teacher where email in (SELECT email from person where fname like "%'.$form_string.'%" OR lname like "%'.$form_string.'%"));';
$queryExe=mysqli_query($connection,$sqlQuery);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryExe)

 ?>
<div class="panel-body">
                    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryExe)) { ?>
                    <article class="row panel panel-default">

                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3  col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-0">
                            <a href="#" title="Lorem ipsum" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/profile-default.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i>
                                    <span>
                                        <?php
                                            echo " ".$row["description"];
                                        ?>
                                    </span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <?php

                                    echo "<span id=\"CourseID-".$row['courseid']." \" >";
                                    echo " Course ID ".$row["courseid"];
                                    echo "</span>";

                                    ?>
                                    </li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></i>
                                    <span>
                                        <?php echo" Rs. ".$row["fees"];
                                        ?>
                                    </span>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                            <h3>
                                <a href="#" title="">
                                    <?php 
                                        $sql_profile = 
                                            "SELECT `fname`,`lname`,`email`
                                                FROM `person` 
                                                WHERE `email`=(
                                                    SELECT `email` 
                                                    FROM `teacher` 
                                                    WHERE `user_teacher`=".$row["user_teacher"]."
                                                    );   
                                                ";

                                        $result_sql=mysqli_query($connection,$sql_profile);
                                        $tName = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_sql);
                                        echo $tName["fname"]." ".$tName["lname"];
                                        $_SESSION['temail']= $tName["email"];
                                    ?>
                                </a>
                            </h3>
                            <h6><?php echo $tName['email']; ?></h6>
                            <p class="hidden-xs"><?php echo $row["course_title"]; ?></p>
                            <span class="plus">
                                <a href="#" title="Enroll" class="btn btn-success" id="enrollci"
                                  <?php
                                   /* if(loggedIn()){

                                         echo 'data-toggle="modal" data-target="#enroll "';

                                    }else{

                                        echo 'data-toggle="modal" data-target="#LOGIN "';
                                    }
                                    /**/
                                  ?>>
                                  <?php
                                    echo "<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-plus\" id=\"enroll\" data-id=\"CourseID-".$row["courseid"]." \"></i>";
                                    echo "<span>Enroll</span>";
                                    ?>
                                </a>
                            </span>
                        </div>          
                    </article>
                    <?php 
                     }
                    ?>
                </div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    /*$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#enrollci').click(function() {
            console.log(  $(this).parents('article').find("#CourseID,h6").text());
        });
    });/**/

    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#enrollci').click(function() {
        CourseID = $(this).attr('data-id');
        console.log(CourseID);
        console.log($("#"+CourseID+",h6").text());
        });
    });/**/
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example code below, the enroll button is using the ID as a selector which is not going to work correctly as you have multiple buttons with the same ID. IDs should be unique. When you click on the button you want it to act only on that instance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#enrollci').click(function() { 
        CourseID = $(this).attr('data-id');
        console.log(CourseID);
        console.log($("#"+CourseID+",h6").text());
    });
});
```

Try to use a more appropriate selector such as `a.enroll` and bind it using `.on` (see http://api.jquery.com/on/). In this example you would need to add `enroll` to the buttons class when generating the html.

```
$(document).on('click','a.enroll', function() {
    var CourseID = $(this).attr('data-id');
    console.log(CourseID);
    console.log($("#"+CourseID+",h6").text());
});
```